# Is there an automated way of color correcting using a color card in Capture One?

Tags: color-management, color-correction, capture-one

With the [X-Rite Colorchecker Passport](http://xritephoto.com/colorchecker-passport/support) and their accompanying software, it's really simple to generate a DNG profile to get perfectly accurate colors in Lightroom.

[image: Using X-Rite's Colorchecker Passport with Lightroom]

I want to know if there's a similarly automated way of perfectly correcting colors—**via the X-Rite Colorchecker or any color reference**—in Capture One. Here's the workflow I am looking for:

1. Set up lighting.
2. Take a shot of the color card.
3. Do the photo shoot.
4. Import photos into Capture One.
5. On the shot of the color card, adjust white balance by clicking on a grey square.
6. **On the same shot of the color card, do some magic to perfectly align colors.**
7. Apply to these adjustments to all the remaining shots.

It's that magical step six that I'm looking for. I've seen [how to do this manually](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zAq88VeYcG4). I'm wondering if there's an automated (fast, repeatable) way of doing this.

(I'm fully aware that Capture One uses ICC profiles only and X-rite instead outputs DNG profiles.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use X-Rite's i1Profiler software. Unlike the ColorChecker Passport software, it can create ICC profiles from the ColorChecker that Phase One can use. It looks like it only comes bundled with one of the X-Rite i1 products.

See: http://www.colourspace.xyz/creating-camera-profiles-for-capture-one/

Answer (score 1):

After some searching around I found the following information that a user posted after being frustrated that Capture One only supports ICC profiles but X-Rite creates DNG profiles:

From [robertharringtonstudios.wordpress.com](https://robertharringtonstudios.wordpress.com/2010/11/11/the-x-rite-color-checker-passport-and-capture-one/):

> I discovered that if you are using Capture One, all you need to do is photograph the Munsell Color Target and use the Auto Color Correction button to have the software completely correct the file.
>
> First I take a custom white balance off the neutral target.
>
> Then I photograph the target and bring that into Capture One as well.
>
> Then I hit the A for Auto Adjust in Capture One and get a corrected image.
>
> After that, I just copy and paste my adjustments to my photos and I’m done.

Comment: Thanks for tracking that article down. I'm not sure I really buy his argument. I think Auto Adjust is merely algorithmically optimizing color based on all of the pixels in the entire photo, rather than aligning colors based on a fundamental understanding of the exact colors in the color target and how they should look.

Comment: Ah interesting. I think if this doesn't work, you are simply out of luck unless one of the products decide to support the other format. I found many many references to the current limitation.

Comment: To be clear, I'm happy with ANY automated solution to the problem of perfect color calibration for each lighting situation. If there's another color target that Capture One does support, that will work for me.

Comment: Switch to Lightroom.

Answer (score 0):

It works the same way in COP. Just take a sample with the eyedropper and then tell COP to use that profile for all images that follow.

Answer (score -2):

Since it's supported in Lightroom, couldn't you do the magic correcting in Lightroom which would get the colors looking like they should on the screen. Then use that exported image and bring it into Capture One to guide your correcting in Capture One?